# Rails Active Admin Select or Create New

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, activeadmin

I have a list of products and i have a supplier associated with the product. So when you add the product select the supplier from a dropdown. But If the supplier doesn't exist, i want the ability for the user to add a new supplier via a + icon next to the dropdown box which opens a new tab with suppliers/new. I've looked into the select2 addon, but it doesn't give me what I need.

Answer (score 0):

https://select2.org/tagging

Please look at the select2's dynamic option creation. However documentation is hard to understand.
May be you can think of using modals like this type of situations.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the `activeadmin_addons` gem. It turns select fields into select2 by default and with the `tags` option you can enable the creation of new options:

`app/admin/products.rb`

```rb
form do |f|
  f.input :supplier, tags: true
end
```

I would've expected Select2 to send a create request when selecting a new option, however, it will send the name of the new option in the `supplier_id` param. Nevertheless we can work with that:

`app/admin/products.rb`

```rb
controller do
  def create_supplier
    return unless params.dig('product', 'supplier_id').is_a?(String)

    params['product']['supplier_id'] = Supplier.create!(name: params['product']['supplier_id']).id
  end

  def update
    create_supplier
    super
  end

  def create
    create_supplier
    super
  end
end
```